# Is there a way to know if a System.Web.HttpRequest is a XMLHttpRequest from Global.asax?

Tags: c#, xmlhttprequest, global-asax, httpcontext

in Global.asax.cs, I'm trying to filter out all the XHR requests in order to log them.

However, both the `HttpContext.Current.Request`  and the  `HttpContext.Current.Response` don't seem to provide this information.

Is there some property field I missed? Or is there another way of knowing if a request is XHR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MVC you can use the IsAjaxRequest() extension method.

```
Request.IsAjaxRequest();
```

It's defined in System.Web.Mvc so if you don't already have a `using` statement for that namespace you'll need to add one.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
        {
            if (Context.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit ? (Flagged as low quality by SO)